# django admin filter forein key model when creating

Tags: python, sql, django, foreign-keys, wagtail

I have 2 models, one is fk of another. I want when creating model filter fk on username creating. I know how to do this in sql, but don't understand how to do in django. I thought about api, am I right? Or I can do it in models or admin interface?

```
class Post_links( models.Model):
    post_id = ParentalKey('Post')
    username_can_see=models.CharField(max_length=30, default='') 
class Post( models.Model):
        some_link =models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

now on creating new post when I ll check links I want to see only the links can see current user. How can I write this&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs, they are quite helpful an easy to read. Here the Django queryset docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/
The queryset is the way to query the DB using the Django ORM

Comment: I read this. I can filter in views in output for site, but for admin I cant do this. I filtered for admin output, got current user rows, but when I ckick to add new, I can see al foreignkey keys :( and I dont know what to do

Comment: I think I didn't understand your requirements complete ^^. What exactly is your Szenario? You want to create a new entry of which object in Admin (?) And then what should happen?

Comment: Ok. Look. when you adding something, django goes to models and compile it. When I choose something in adminm and I see all foreghn keys of model I want to add, and I want to filter this foreighn keys for current logged user.

Comment: ok, I think you are looking for `raw_id_fields = ('user',)` in in admin as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

This replaces the dropdown (which I would recommend for all admin FKs) with an input field and a magnifying glas which links to a search dialog.

With this you can search manually for e.g. a User, if the users should be prefiltered you need some aditional modifications to the admin.

Comment: I tried it in wagtail, but no effect. I found https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/48949e69a7a7039cb751f1ee33ecb32187004030/wagtail/wagtailadmin/compare.py   
row 131:
   class ForeignObjectComparison(FieldComparison):
       def get_objects(self):
           model = self.field.related_model
           obj_a = model.objects.filter(id=self.val_a).first()
           obj_b = model.objects.filter(id=self.val_b).first()
   return obj_a, obj_b
I need to return obj_a = model.objects.filter(id=self.val_a).filter(user=self.username).first()=self.val_a).filter(user=self.username).first()

Comment: öhm, which admin do you mean, django damin or wagtail?

Comment: I mean wagtail admin, or some another way to do it. I need to do authorised page/view. Admin fuctionality looks fine. Or its not best practise?

Comment: So I don't know about wagtail, never used it before. But for Django Admin my solution would work. BUT it's not a good way to use Django Admin for daily tasks because you are working direktly with the internals of Django, there is no safety net. Since I cannot help you with the wagtail admin thing you should update your question with more details and perhaps also a screenshot to clarify your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm searching the soulution. What is the best way? to make authorizedview for my model and html file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155397/discussion-between-mihail-and-johannes-reichard).